# Aligning three tables vertically for tablets

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to align 3 tables so they form 1 big table.
The reason I want to do this is because I want to have scrollable table which works on tablets(ipad, android). I already got this working the only thing I still need to do is align the headers and footers with the content. My table layout looks like this :

```
<!-- Fixed header table -->
<table data-role="table" class="ui-body-d ui-shadow table-stripe ui-responsive">
 <thead>
    <th> Header 1 </th>
    <th> Header 2 </th>
    <th> Header 3 </th>
 </thead>
</table>
<!--  Scrollable content table -->
<div class="scroll"> <!--  This div enables the table to be scrollable -->
 <table data-role="table" class="ui-body-d ui-shadow table-stripe ui-responsive">
  <thead> <!--  Use a thead or JQuery Mobile 1.4 gets mad -->
    <tr> </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!--  This is dynamically filled -->
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
<!--  Fixed footer table -->
<table data-role="table" class="ui-body-d ui-shadow table-stripe ui-responsive">
 <thead> 
   <tr> </tr>
 </thead>
 <tfoot>
  <tr>
   <td> Footer 1 </td>
   <td> Footer 2 </td>
   <td> Footer 3 </td>
   </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

I already tried to give every cell a max width but it didn't seem to work.
Isn't there a default solution for this ?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I want it to be aligned like this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRqmt.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set table-layout to be fixed then only width works as expected.

```
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
}
th,td{
    width: 50px;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aBydf/)

---

table has auto by default so it will increase the width as your contents increases and by setting to fixed to will be fixed width.

Comment: Thanks but I checked your JSFiddle but the header and the footer aren't aligned.

Comment: how do you want can you place a pic or draw by lines in your question.